# grab data-id attribute using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to grab the value of a data-id attribute. I am able to get the desired result using `dataset` but I need to support IE 9 and 10 if possible.

```
<div class="youtube-player" data-id="{{youtubeID}}"></siv>

    var players = document.querySelectorAll('.player');
    var videoID = $('.youtube-player');

    for (var i = 0; i < players.length; i++) {
      videoId: videoID[i].dataset.id
    };
```

There can be multiple `<div class="video-player" data-id="{{youtubeID}}"></div>`on a page which is why I am using a for loop. I have tried using `data('data-id)` and `attr('data-id`). What am I missing?

Thanks

---

Comment: `videoID[i].getAttribute('data-id')`

Comment: jQuery - `$('.player').each(function() {
  var id = $(this).data('id');
  console.log(id);
});
`

Comment: `for (var i = 0; i < players.length; i++) {
  var videoId = videoID[i].dataset ? videoID[i].dataset.id : videoID[i].getAttribute('data-id');
  console.log(videoId)
};
`